# not able to read Special characters from oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, encoding, special-characters

I am reading some text data from oracle database in python. where I have to flag values which have some special characters and change it to something specific based on its value
Some names have special characters like ą,Ł etc.

While some are getting read as they are. But ą is being read as A. As a result, even when the data value in Database is a special character, my python code is not flagging it.

I even tried using encoding='iso-8859-1' while connecting to the DB, but instead of reading and showing the character as it is , its showing an inverted question mark.

Please help me on how to read these characters in python as it is.

I am using cx_Oracle for connecting to the database.
column in the DB has a value: Mąrią.

without using any encoding while connecting to db, python is reading this value as Maria.
But I want it in the same form as it is in the db
i.e Expected_output : Mąrią.
Bt the output I am getting if i add encoding='iso-8859-1' is  'M¿ri¿'

```
import cx_Oracle
conn=cx_Oracle.connect('username','pwd','hostname/servicename')
c=conn.cusrsor()
sql='select name from con where id='123' #output of this in db is :Mąrią
z=pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
```

output in python: Maria

expected output: same as it is in DB i.e: Mąrią

if I change the connect to:
conn=cx_Oracle.connect('username','pwd','hostname/servicename',encoding='iso- 8859-1')

output in python: 'M¿ri¿'

expected output: same as it is in DB i.e: Mąrią

Comment: which characterset do you have in your database ? are you using cx_Oracle ?? Provide a test case of what happens : code, result, expected result

Comment: can you provide the code and what you are getting of it ?

Comment: edited the post

Comment: do you know the database characterset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the encoding and nencoding properties of the object connect, and also I would load your NLS_LANG variable before executing the connect ( if you use cx_Oracle prior to 8.0. If you use cx_Oracle 8.0, you don't need to do it ). It is better always use UTF-8 because it is by far the most suitable one.

```
import os
import cx_Oracle
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = 'YOUR_NLS_LANG_VARIABLE'
conn=cx_Oracle.connect('username','pwd','hostname/servicename',encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
c=conn.cusrsor()
sql='select name from con where id='123' #output of this in db is :Mąrią
z=pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
```

Example

My python program

```
import os
import cx_Oracle
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = 'american_america.al32utf8'
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("TEST", "test_1", "180.22.128.47:60995/odcgrc1r" , encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("select 'Maria and ÄeÜöI' from dual")
while True:
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        break
    print(row)
```

Running on my windows

```
 c:\python>python.exe c:\python\examples\testoracle.py
('Maria and ÄeÜöI',)

c:\python>
```

**Update**

If you are using cx_Oracle 8.0, the default value is UTF-8:

Setting the Client Character Set
In cx_Oracle 8 the default encoding used for all character data changed to “UTF-8”. This universal encoding is suitable for most applications. If you have a special need, you can pass the encoding and nencoding parameters to the cx_Oracle.connect()

Comment: Thank you for the answer. my issue was resolved using this. I just have one query, what is the reason for passing two parameters encoding and nencoding?  It gave me the required output by using only encoding parameter also. Please let me know the difference.

Comment: The important note is that the character set component of NLS_LANG is ignored from cx_Oracle 8 onwards, so use the `encoding` and `nencoding` options when connecting instead if the new default UTF-8 needs changing.

Comment: Hi @ROma. The encoding parameter affects character data such as VARCHAR2 and CLOB columns. The nencoding parameter affects “National Character” data such as NVARCHAR2 and NCLOB. If you are not using national character types, then you can omit nencoding.

Comment: Hi @ROma. if you consider that the answer resolves your issue, please accept it.